# jQuery cascade dropdown not working on iPhone when tabbing to next dropdown

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, cascadingdropdown

My cascading dropdowns work well on desktop browsers and the iPad, but I really only need it to work on the iPhone on iOS 7 and Android. The problem is with the iPhone. After I choose an option on the first dropdown if I navigate to the next dropdown using the > button, it switches before the ajax call completes, so my dropdown is either empty or still holding the previous choices. If I hit Done, the blur event is sufficient to make it work.

Here is the simplest fully functional example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Cascading dropdowns" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Cascade</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="main">
      <div data-role="header" class="jqm-header">
        <h1>Cascade</h1>
     </div>
     <div data-role="content" >
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <select name="agency" id="agency" >
              <option value="actransit">AC Transit</option>
              <option value="emery">Emeryville</option>
              <option value="sf-muni">MUNI</option>
          </select>
          <select name="selectRoute" id="selectRoute"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script>
    var nextBus = "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?";

    function updateRoutes(agency) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: nextBus + "command=routeList&a=" + agency,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $("#selectRoute").children().remove();
                    $(xml).find('route').each(function(){
                        var tag = $(this).attr('tag');
                        var title = $(this).attr('title');
                        $('<option value="' + tag + '">' + title+ '</option>').appendTo("#selectRoute");
                    });
                    $("#selectRoute").selectmenu('refresh');
                }
            });
    }

    $().ready(function(){

        $("#agency").blur (function (event)
        {
            var agency = $("#agency").val();
            updateRoutes(agency);
       });

    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On some browsers, the > button could be simulated by pressing the tab key. I've tried adding this to delay the focus change until after the ajax completes:

```
    $("#selectAgency").keypress (function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            tabHappened = true;
            updateRoutes($("#selectAgency").val());
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
```

Then after populating the next dropdown, calling:

```
                if (tabHappened) {
                  tabHappened = false;
                  $("#selectRoute").focus();
                }
```

But neither keypress, keydown, nor a few others I tried seem to trigger, or there is something else going on. I don't have a way to monitor which events are happening on the iPhone's safari browser. I appreciate any insight in getting the quick navigation buttons on the iPhone to work with this. Thanks in advance for taking the time to look this over.

Comment: Having received no responses, I've concluded the only way to solve this one is to make the ajax call synchronous.

Comment: I think your going to want this. I feel your pain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472465/disabling-previous-and-next-buttons-in-mobile-safari

Answer (score 1):

Using async=false for your ajax will prevent all subsequent events from firing until it is complete. see [What does "async: false" do in jQuery.ajax()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

Comment: The answer is to use async=false because it prevents other events from firing. the link just supports that fact and does not talk about this scenario at all. so the answer is not in the link