# Is it possible to refresh the iPhone UIPicker from with in a web page

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, mobile-website

We have 2 select elements in a web page. The options in 1 are dependent on the selections made in the other. When the user changes a selection in the 1st drop down via the UIPicker the resultant changes in the 2nd drop down are not reflected in the picker. We have close the picker and reopen it to see the changes. Is it possible to force the picker to refresh from the web page?

Comment: The plugin from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960731/strange-behavior-of-select-dropdowns-onchange-js-event-when-using-next-on-m/7284325#7284325) worked for me. It appears to be loading the second list as soon as you select the item in the first list instead of waiting until the user hits 'next' or 'done'