# iOS Javascript <select><option> not populating list when tapping 'next'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, select

I've found a strange bug in iOS on my iPod Touch running iOS 4.1.

I have two `<select>` drop-downs next to each other. The first one contains the month, the second contains the days of the month. When changing the 'month' value, the 'days' list will auto-update to show the day and number ('Wednesday 1st', 'Thursday 2nd', and so on, for example).

What's happening is that the data is being generated correctly and placed in the `<select> <option>` elements, as I can see the drop-down value change. But in the iOS vertical slider which appears at the bottom of the screen, the **old** values are still visible! It seems that iOS is populating its scrolling list before the new values are added to the drop-down.

If you de-select the 'days' list by clicking on the page or the 'done' button, then re-select it, you'll see the correct values. It works as expected on desktop browsers, and even works on iPad (as there's no prev/next buttons for `<select>` elements on iPad, it works like a desktop browser would).

Does anyone have any clues how to work around this?

Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qGjWp/5/ When tapping 'next' to move from the month box, you'll notice that the visible value in the `<select>` box doesn't match the list of options!

---

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot of the bug in action - "Sun 1" is the correct value for the first day of April 2012, but the scrolling list at the bottom shows the values for the previously chosen month.

[image: iOS select element bug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle to reflect the best solution I have been able to find for this problem. It's explained well in [this answer to a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960731/strange-behavior-of-select-dropdowns-onchange-js-event-when-using-next-on-m/7284325#7284325).

http://jsfiddle.net/qGjWp/12/

Comment: Many thanks - I searched for ages and couldn't find those questions or anything like them! And you also get a bonus point for spotting the unintentional mistake I added when I updated the jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

try `html` instead of `append` avoid old values and display only one at a time

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it makes no difference, same problem exists.