# iOS Bug? Unable to change text in a select when focused using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iphone, focus, optgroup

I am using a select with optgroups for some navigation on mobile devices. I use the optgroup's label to indicate the section it belongs in - and then the option itself to designate the sub-section.

The problem is that in pretty much every browser I come across doesn't show the optgroup when the select is not in focus. I got around this by writing the following jQuery:

```
$(".Nav-Interior-Mobile select option:selected").each( function() {
    pageGroupLabel = $(this).parent('optgroup').attr('label');
    pageItemLabel = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(pageGroupLabel + " > " + pageItemLabel);
});
$('.Nav-Interior-Mobile select').focus( function() {
    $(this).find('option:selected').text(pageItemLabel); 
});
$('.Nav-Interior-Mobile select').blur( function() {
    $(this).find('option:selected').text(pageGroupLabel + " > " + pageItemLabel); 
});
```

This appears to work in everything but iOS. In iOS the UI to change a select doesn’t reflect the new text that gets used on focus. I can see the actual select above Apple's UI changing - but their UI doesn’t change at all.

Anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Here it is working when blurred:

[image: http://files.secondstreetmedia.com/support/todd/blurred.PNG]

And not working when focused (their UI still has "Branding > Web" when it should just say "Web"):

[image: http://files.secondstreetmedia.com/support/todd/focused-2.jpg]

---

This absolutely has to be a bug - if you scroll down and then back up in the list - the text is then changed - bizarre.

Comment: If you're certain it's a bug why don't you log a bug at Apple?

Comment: I'm hoping someone here has a workaround or can suggest a different solution to the problem.

Comment: Also I did post a bug there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the quickChange plugin posted here:

[Strange behavior of select/dropdown's onchange() JS event when using 'Next' on Mobile Safari Dropdown list item select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960731/strange-behavior-of-select-dropdowns-onchange-js-event-when-using-next-on-m/7284325#7284325)

After pasting the plugin code into your Javascript file, you should be able to replace your onfocus code with this:

```
$('.Nav-Interior-Mobile select').quickChange(function() { 
    $(this).find('option:selected').text(pageItemLabel);
});
```

And your existing onblur code should continue to work for changing the value back.

Answer (score 0):

Why do this in the first place? You should not mess up the design for select/option. You can add a "label" "div" on top "select", set the "select" opacity 0, if you want to add custom Text do it on the added "DIV". In Short, it's like this :

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <div class="color-label"> YOUR COLOR : <span id="selectedColor"></span></div>
    <select class="color-select">
        <option value="blue" selected="selected"> Blue</option>
        <option value="green"> Green</option>
        <option value="red"> Red</option>
        <option value="orange"> Orange</option>
        <option value="white"> White</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.select-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}

.color-label {
    position: absolute;
}
.color-select{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JQUERY SCRIPT:

```
$(".color-select").on('change',function(){
    var optionSelected = $('>option:selected',this);
    $('#selectedColor').text(optionSelected.text());
  });
```

Fiddle HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/w8t39bm1/1/