# jQuery select change fires every other time on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, select, safari, onchange

As the title describes it I'm having an issue with select boxes and firing the change event on them on iOS Safari.
I've got the following code:

```
$thisPage.find('select#id-attribute').on('change', function (e) {
    var theId = $(this).val();

    $thisPage.find('.place-where-options-get-populated').empty();

    if (theId != '') {
        $.ajax({'type': 'GET', 'url': '/the-actual-url'+ theId, 'dataType': 'json'})
            .done(showTemplate)
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            })
    } else {
        showTemplate({});
    }

}).trigger('change');
```

The above code works fine on desktop browsers -the output options change accordingly on each change event- whereas on iOS the options only change every second time (works on first change, doesn't on the second, works on the 3rd, doesn't on the 4th, etc). 
I'm using **jQuery v3.2.1**

A guide in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

**Edit**:
showTemplate() function is basically the requests which I'm doing to the server and it ends in the following (the part which has to do with my issue):

```
$thisPage.find('.place-where-options-get-populated').html(theItems);
```

Now, if do a console.log on 'theItems' this always returns what it should return. Furthermore the content actually gets added to its appropriate container, just that it doesn't show up on the page.

Comment: What does the showTemplate on ajax request do

Comment: useful link for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960731/strange-behavior-of-select-dropdowns-onchange-js-event-when-using-next-on-m

Comment: @l.g.karolos - please see the Edit section of my post.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - tried that fix, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I got around fixing this issue by adding a hide() and show() on that last bit of the showTemplate() function. So it looks like this:

```
$thisPage.find('.place-where-options-get-populated').hide().html(theItems).show();
```

Basically, the issue lies right there with the html() function.

Might not be the ideal solution, but it'll do the job.